# jQuery DataTable Custom Pagination Button

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using `jQuery dataTables` plugins for displaying data, and one scenario I need to customize pagination button like bellow

**`<<< Action 1 of 3 >>>`**

I tried `"dom": '<"#df"<"pull-right"i p>>',` and output  is like bellow

```
Action 1 of 3
<<<  >>>
```

I want the info inside paging buttons. Can any one please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to replace and add texts in your pagination block.

As your DataTable option, try the following:

```
"pagingType": "simple",
```

^ Changes pagination format for previous' and 'Next' buttons only.

For replacing and adding of texts in your pagination block, inside your table draw event handler, do:

```
dTable.on( 'draw', function () {
    $('.paginate_button.previous').html("<<<");
    $('.paginate_button.next').html(">>>");
    var total_records = dTable.rows().count();
    var page_length = dTable.page.info().length;
    var total_pages = Math.ceil(total_records / page_length);
    var current_page = dTable.page.info().page+1;
    $('.paginate_button.previous').after("<strong>Action "+current_page+" of "+(page_length<0?1:total_pages)+"</strong>");
} );
```

Note: change `dTable` to the variable name you initialized your `DataTable(..)` with.

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the variable name is? In your linked example with `$('#example').DataTable` is the id `#example` the var name? Or should this be declared separately somehow?