# Moving or adding file export button to row of pagination buttons in Datatables with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, datatables, bootstrap-5

Datatables work beautifully in Bootstrap 5 theme, with pagination and [file export](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) functionality working well, but the file export button doesn't match the theme and I want it unobtrusively down in the same row as pagination buttons.

Simplification of page:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<title>filename</title>
  <table id="myTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Tiger Nixon</td><td>System Architect</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Garrett Winters</td><td>Accountant</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ashton Cox</td><td>Junior Technical Author</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Senior Javascript Developer</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Airi Satou</td><td>Accountant</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',buttons: ['csv'],pageLength: 2,
} );} );
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Bootstrap 5 [Buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/) and [Button Groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/) look great, so we could make Datatables' pagination buttons hidden and bind other buttons to them, but I don't know how we could manage varying numbers of buttons.

I thought the easiest approach might be to append another button to the pagination row, but this didn't create the button as expected:

```js
var node = document.createElement("LI");                  
node.className = "paginate_button page-item " 
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");                             
document.querySelector(".pagination").appendChild(node);
```

[This was the only answer I could find related to this, which discusses customizing buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50521579/4107349).

What am I doing wrong? What's a simple way we can add a button to the row of pagination buttons and then bind it to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Append it to `.pagination` class:

```js
var append_li = '<li class="paginate_button json_button" id="json_button"><a aria-controls="myTable" class="page-link">JSON</a></li>';
$('.pagination').append(append_li); 
$('.json_button').click(function() { $('.dt-button').trigger('click');}); // bind new btn to file export btn
$('.dt-buttons').hide(); // hide file export btn
```

When navigation buttons are used the table is redrawn, so repeat this when buttons are clicked:

```js
$('#myTable').on('draw.dt', function () { // when the table is redrawn the export btn must be readded and rebound to hidden export btn
    $('.pagination').append(append_li);
    $('.json_button').click(function() { $('.dt-button').trigger('click');});
                                         });
```